# Reference Nested JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I have this code:

```
var string = { 
            nameString : "nameValue",
            nameString2 : "nameValue2",
            nameString3 : "nameValue3",
            datathing : 0,
        };

var data = { 
            data : 1,
            dataNum2 : 2,
            dataNum3 : 3,
            dataNum4 : 4,
        };

var thing = { 
            datathing1 : 10,
            datathing2 : 20,
            datathing3 : 30,
            datathing4 : 40,
        };

var object = { 
            object1 : string,
            data1 : data,
            thing1 : thing,
        };
```

Why do neither of these means to access the data work:

```
alert("testReference= " + object['object1']['string']['nameString']);
alert("testReference= " + object.object1.string.nameString);
```

I cannot understand it, even though similar examples found below and textbooks state explicitly that they should work:

[Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

Thanks in advance for any input!

I am currently constructing an object and passing it around, a 'for in' will bring up the values but a 'typeof' test or any other way I try and access will not work, either I will encounter an error (which breaks the program, I think) or I get 'undefined'....

One last thing if this gets solved, is it ok to nest a key that is the same name value as its parent, such as data.data - this leads to the possibility of further nesting such as data.data.data...

Comment: object1 has no "string" property... you want object['object1']['nameString']

Comment: dammit you are right, I thought it might be a related issue but cannot see where I am going wrong in the code I am writing! (which isn't the example, by the way, but a similar construct which I couldn't get to work either)

Answer (score 3):

Let's look at what's wrong with each example, then take a look at the way that works right.

**Example 1**

`object['object1']['string']['nameString']`

1. We expect `object['object1']` to return the object `string`, right? So lets simplify the big expression by replacing that part of it. That'll make it easier for us to understand.
2. So now we have `string['string']['nameString']`.
3. But `string` has no member called 'string', so `string['string']` returns `undefined`.
4. And when you try to treat `undefined` as an object, you get an error!

**Example 2**

`object.object1.string.nameString`

1. We expect `object.object1` returns the object `string`, right? So lets simplify the big expression by replacing that part of it. That'll make it easier for us to understand.
2. So now we have `string.string.nameString`.
3. But `string` has no member called 'string', so `string.string` returns `undefined`.
4. And when you try to treat `undefined` as an object, you get an error!.

**What You Want**

`object.object1.nameString` (or `object['object1']['nameString']`)

1. We expect `object.object1` returns the object `string`, right? So lets simplify the big expression by replacing that part of it. That'll make it easier for us to understand.
2. So now we have `string.nameString`, and we expect that to return `"nameValue"`.
3. And it does!