# JS get nested property of object with space in name

Tags: javascript

Given this structure:

```
{  
    "foo":{  
        "bar":{  
            "baz":[  
                {  
                    "foo bar":"baz",
                    "baz foo":"bar"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

How can I select 'foo bar' from a variable such as:

```
var myString = "baz[0]['baz foo']";
```

There are many examples of how to do it using dot notation:

[Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key)

[Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

[Reference Nested JavaScript Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17870272/reference-nested-javascript-object)

But none of them support key with spaces in it seems.

An example [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WmYEX/88/)

Comment: Correct myString to this - foo.bar.baz[0]['baz foo']

Comment: Sorry I obviously didn't explain the question well enough, the string was just an example, I'll need to recurse over the object

Comment: Your question is still not very clear. Try to elaborate and present a test case.

Comment: @OriDrori added JSFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with parsing the path of properties, as using split ignores the [] and the "". This regex `prop.match(/[^.\[\]'"]+/g)` extracts all props ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yzjh9tta/)):

```
function getProperty(obj, prop) {
    var parts = prop.match(/[^.\[\]'"]+/g),
        i = 0,
        current = parts[0];

    var currentValue = obj;

    while (currentValue[current]) {
        currentValue = currentValue[current];

        current = parts[++i];
    }

    if(i < parts.length) {
        return undefined;
    }

    return currentValue;
}
```

I'm sure that I didn't get all edge cases, and errors, but that's a good place to start. You should also check lodash [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs#get), which does exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

baz is an array of objects

```js
var obj = {  
    "foo":{  
        "bar":{  
            "baz":[  
                {  
                    "foo bar":"baz",
                    "baz foo":"bar"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
var myString = obj.foo.bar.baz[0]['baz foo'];
alert(myString);
```

**Updated**
you can use [`.eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) method.

```js
var obj = {  
    "foo":{  
        "bar":{  
            "baz":[  
                {  
                    "foo bar":"baz",
                    "baz foo":"bar"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
};
var myString = "obj.foo.bar.baz[0]['baz foo']";
alert(eval(myString));
```

Comment: Updated the string to explain more, assume my variable is as above